# Efficient calculation of minimal expected number of inversions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, expectation

**Problem:** I have an array of size n with Z inversions initially and I am allowed to perform K operations where each operation can be

1. decrease the number of inversions by 1.
2. make a random shuffle of the array.

My problem is to perform the k operations in such a way that the expected number of inversions in the final array are minimized.

**Constraints:** 
100s of testcases with
1 < n < 100
1 < K < n(n-1)/2

**My approach:** I am thinking about Dynamic programming based solution. I can calculate the probabilities of having exactly e inversions in an array of size n using mahonian numbers. I also fill an array dp[k+1][1+n(n-1)/2] row wise such that dp[i][j] denotes the minimal expected inversions in the array having j inversions after i operations have been performed and then for each testcase  using it I can generate the minimal expected value for (i+1)<sup>th</sup> operation for all possible inversions in the array.

The problem with this approach the probabilities are not accurate due to the limitation of doubles in c++ and this algorithm is O(kn<sup>2</sup>) for each test case which is very slow.

Probability of having no inversion in an array of size 100 = 1.0/factorial(100) ~ 10<sup>-160</sup>,

Even double precision is unable to solve it accurately.

I think that there is some accurate and more efficient approach.

Thank you in advance